# How to stop Music app from automatically launching when CD is inserted on MacOS Catalina

Tags: catalina, music.app

I am presently running MacOS Catalina (10.15.1).

1. Within System Preferences, I have set CD's to do nothing upon being inserted:

[image: System Preferences, "CD & DVD" settings]

2. Within the Music app preferences, there is ***NO*** option to disable the app from opening when a CD is inserted:

[image]

The only options available in the highlighted dropdown are:

- Show CD
- Play CD
- Import CD
- Import CD and eject
- Ask to Import CD.

Why Apple would have one setting that informs the computer not to do something, but another that overrides that confounds me.

My issue is that I don't want the app to start when I insert a CD and I don't know how to resolve this, short of deleting the entire app because it's getting to be *very* annoying.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205913/itunes-opens-automatically-when-cd-inserted

Comment: @pkamb Thank you for posting that. Toggling the setting in System Preferences, as suggested by one of the answers, appears to have resolved the issue for the time being. Will monitor and report back if the issue returns.